# ModelViewSet mixing up url patterns in retrieve method

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a ModelViewSet defined. Based on my requirements, all my view methods should work with certain url pattern which follow something like this:

```
/api/app/system_name/subsystem_name/object_name
```

These I extract from `kwargs` in the `get_queryset` method and filter the queries.

Now, for my retrieve, delete and put methods, I also need to get a `pk`, so the API address should be:

```
/api/app/system_name/subsystem_name/object_name/pk
```

my problem is, when I do add a `pk` value to the url, the `kwargs` is all messed up and looks something like this:

```
{'system_name': 'system_name/subsystem_name', 'subsystem_name': 'object_name', 'object_name': 'pk'}
```

I need my list method to work with this:

```
/api/app/system_name/subsystem_name/object_name
```

and my delete, put, and retrieve methods to work like this:

```
/api/app/system_name/subsystem_name/object_name/pk
```

This is how my router is registered and my urlpattern:

```
router.register("(?P<system_name>.+)/(?P<subsystem_name>.+)/(?P<object_name>.+)", MyModelViewSet, basename="list_viewset")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

I just can't get this to work right. I've read the documentations and many questions and answers here and still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was paying for my lack of understanding in Regular Expressions.

I changed the regex I used for the router register and everything works just fine.

```
router.register("(?P<system_name>[^/]+)/(?P<subsystem_name>[^/]+)/(?P<object_name>[^/]+)", MyModelViewSet, basename="list_viewset")
```